# MongoDB: find the common area of two polygons

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

thanks in advance for all the help.
I have two complex polygons that are overlapping.
I need to get the border of the area that is overlapping.
[image: Polygon A (purple border) and Polygon B (green border)]

I have the coordinates of the borders of these two polygons and I want to get back the coordinates of the borders of the yellow area.

I have tried getting $geoWithing coordinates of each in the other, but then the coordinates aren't ordered and I can't draw the polygon correctly.
And with $geoIntersects I get only the coordinates of the intersections of the borders, which is not enough to draw the desired area.
Somebody must have done this before so I hope it reaches someone that can help.

```
//Get first zone coordinates within zone 2
var zoneOneArea = db.zone.find(
{
    "name":"Zone 1",
    "location":
    {
        $geoWithin:
        {
            $polygon: zoneTwoCoordinatesArray
        }
    }
});
//Get zone 2 coordinates within zone 1
var zoneTwoArea = db.zone.find(
{
    "name":"Zone 2",
    "location":
    {
        $geoWithin:
        {
            $polygon: zoneOneCoordinatesArray
        }
    }
});
```

So, this is what I have tried, but I can't get those two results in an ordered fashioned array to be able to draw it correctly.

Comment: MongoDB does not do this. You can combine two `$geoIntersects` in an aggregation pipeline to find the "points" within the intersection area, but not the intersection area itself. You need to retrieve the data and work with an external API of your choice. There are a few popular ones implemented for most languages.

Comment: Ok I see, I need to do this calculation server-side and get it straight organised from the DB. Do you know if PostGIS has such kind of functionality? Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

As [Blakes Seven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5031275/blakes-seven) mentioned,

> MongoDB does not do this

So I stopped using this because I had no simple alternative.

Finally I did this by using PostGIS which has this function implemented ST_Intersection which return exactly what I needed that is the border of the polygon resulted in the intersection.
PostGIS is powerful tool when it comes to Geometry calculations so use it with trust.